# Why is this program not working?

Tags: c++, jgrasp

This is my syntax.  I'm trying to display an average out of the values.  It keeps giving me an error that says: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main()

{
  double value;
  double sumofvalue = 0;
  int numberofvalues = 0;
  const int sentinel = 0;
  while(value!=sentinel){
    cout << "Enter a value (0 to quit): ";
    cin >> value;
    numberofvalues++;
    sumofvalue+=value;
  }
  cout << "Average is "((sumofvalue)/(numberofvalues));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's also important to note that the floating point arithmetic often gives unespected result, that math operation is probably not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: `<iostream.h>` hasn't been correct for 15 years or so. You may be using an archaic compiler or textbook.

Comment: One problem is you never initialized value. So the while () may never enter depending on what random value is on the stack where value is located.

Answer (score 15):

You are missing `<<` in

```
cout << "Average is " << ((sumofvalue)/(numberofvalues));
                      ^^ HERE
```